# Angular: Best practices for angular $watch registration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I'm playing around with handling the query string on page load, and noticed something about $watch.

It looks like it takes some time for $watch to register when it is called - and this process is asynchronous.

I'm finding that I have to deal with race conditions as my $watch does not trigger when it should - that is, values that are set after the $watch declaration do not get evaluated by the $watch.

See this example for an illustration of the problem: http://jsbin.com/kapifezi/24/edit

Does anyone have a best practice around using watches to avoid this type of issue?

Comment: `$watch` registration IS synchronous. But the dirty-checking takes place only one time, at the end of each cycle. In your JSBin, what output do you expect exactly?

Comment: I expected the `$watch` to trigger (without the `$timeout of course`) such that I would see two entries in the console output. I understand now that `$timeout` actually forces a _dirty check_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns  out - after investigating further - I didn't fully understand how $watch worked.

http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/ really helped shed some light on the situation.

As it turns out - simply changing a variable that is being watched won't trigger a digest loop by itself.

The reason `$timeout` worked was because it "safely" makes a call to `$digest` which causes all `$watch` expressions to be evaluated - that is, it was the `$digest` component of the `$timeout` that caused the `$watch` to fire and *not* the wait of 1000 milliseconds.

Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean value updated inside $timeout??? there will be 1000 miliseconds delay before $scope.val is changed to 1 inside $timeout and after that $scope.val gets updated

Comment: right - i understood that - my question was more - why do I need the $timeout in order to get the $watch to trigger?  I think I figured it out in the answer I provided to my question.

Comment: i guess because, $timeout fires another $scope.$apply or $scope.$digest.

Answer (score 0):

Not really got what do you mean but in my controller if I need watch for some var im doing this:

```
$scope.myValue = "value";
$scope.$watch("myValue", function(val) {
    if (val) {
        console.out(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess the idea was that I was trying to figure out why, in my example, the $watch didn't fire after I had changed the value.